# Python: Matplotlib - Set colorspace at the end of loop plotting

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I wonder if there is a possibility to set the color of a histgram, which is filled in a for loop, at the end of this process like:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylot as plt

x=np.array([[1,1,3,4],[1,4,5,6],[1,4,4,6]])
plt.figure()
    for i in range(3):
    plt.hist(x[i])
plt.show()
```

Maybe some comand before the plt.show() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get hold of the [Patch](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Patch.html#matplotlib.patches.Patch) objects which make up the histogram as you go along:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=np.array([[1,1,3,4],[1,4,5,6],[1,4,4,6]])
plt.figure()
patches = []
for i in range(3):
    _, _, p = plt.hist(x[i])
    patches += p

for patch in patches:
    patch.set_color('pink')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

[`plt.hist()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html) has the parameter `color`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array([[1,1,3,4],[1,4,5,6],[1,4,4,6]])
xcolor = ["r", "b", "y"]
plt.hist(x.T, color = xcolor)
plt.show()
```

This parameter works also in a loop, though the code you provided doesn't produce what you probably expect it to do.